# Excel file doesn't have SharedStringTable

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I tried to de-serialize all the data from the excel file to list .
but when in this line:

```
var sharedStringTablePart = workBookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
if (sharedStringTablePart == null)
{
     // report a problem
}
```

sharedStringTablePart reruen null

I checked the file with open XML sdk2.0 productivity tool and I saw that the file dont have **SharedStringTable**

any idea why?

Comment: no... AFAIK this is allowed - so the question is why is this a problem ?

Comment: it is allowed excell to not have SharedStringTable? so how do I create one or how do I de-serialize

Comment: I don't understand your question... what exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I would like to de-serialize excel file .

Comment: and you can do that... with and without a `SharedStringTable`... from my POV de-serializing means that you only process whatever is in the file... if such a `SharedStringTable` is not in the file then de-serialize whatever else is in the file...

Comment: all the example that I found they used `SharedStringTable` in order to de-serializing like [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358824)

Comment: the link you provide talks generally about OpenXML/Excel and about using LINQ with Excel tables... on the first impression there is nothing about de-serializing/SharedStringTable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SharedStringTable is only added if you have text that is not represented in-line in the file.  Excel tends to use an SST, but if you have numerical values only, or some other tool generated your file with in-line strings, then you won't have an SST.  You'd never "deserialize" the SST directly anyway - it's only used to display values from text fields.

Just skip/ignore it and move on.

Comment: Hi, ı am getting same error. I am create one excel file using open xml sdk. And  i want to read with open xml. How can i assign  sst when ı create the excel file?